# dsh no tty present and no askpass program specified

Tags: ssh, tty

I'm using the dancers shell to try and run install commands on multiple machines on the network, but whenever I do I get

`no tty present and no askpass program specified`.

I know that if I use `ssh -t` for the command, I can avoid this, but is there a way to `dsh` or `ssh` to run a command on multiple machines without using the `-t` command?

Command I'm running:

```
`dsh -aM -c sudo apt-get install python`
```

Answer (score 0):

`sudo` by default will read the password from the attached terminal. Your problem is that there is no terminal attached when it is run from the console.

## 1 open /etc/sudoers

type `sudo vi  /etc/sudoers`. This will open your file in edit mode.

## 2 Add/Modify linux user

Look for the entry for Linux user. Modify as below if found or add a new line.

```
<USERNAME> ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

## 3 Save and Exit from edit mode

Answer (score -2):

You can avoid `sudo` requiring TTY by adding this option `Defaults !requiretty` in `/etc/sudoers` file. But if sudo still requires password, than it will not help you, unless you set `NOPASSWD` to your user. Basically the changes you want can look somehow like this:

```
Defaults:your_user !requiretty
your_user ALL = NOPASSWD: ALL
```

Preferred way of editing this file is using `visudo`, which will check syntax before writing the file back to the disk.

Comment: I'm assuming you mean adding that to the visudo, but would I do that for the machine I'm running the command from or do I need to edit the sudo of every machine I'm trying to connect to?

Comment: yes. Using `visudo` is preferred way. You would need to set it up on the remote machines, but if you tested the file, you can just copy it to its place in `/etc/sudoers`. Sorry, I probably missed the file and tool in the answer. Fixing now.